# Docker --volume gives "permission denied: unknown"

Tags: docker, permissions, chmod

I have a very simple `Dockerfile` based on Ubuntu that installs a few packages

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get install -y \
    cmake              \
    g++                \
    git                \
    python3            \
    htop
```

I build it using `docker build -t myimage .`.

Then I try to run it using

```
docker run -it          \
    -w $(pwd)           \
    -v $HOME:$HOME      \
    myimage
```

such that my home directory `/lab/home/me` is mounted, and such that the current directory `/lab/home/me/dev/lib` is set as the working directory.

However I get the following error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: mkdir /lab/home/me/dev: permission denied: unknown.
```

I don't understand because I have the permissions `drwx------` for `/lab/home/me/dev` when I am outside docker, so I can `mkdir` without any issue.

What is the problem exactly?